# How to get width of Paragraph (p) element in Angular app

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I am running an angular app, I want to get width of span element, Based on this value, I want to position this element.

I want to style an element based on formula p2 = p1 + (A-B)/2

P1 is position of first element, p2 is position is second element, A and B are width of element. I have shown this in the pic below.

[image]

I am doing this because I want p element ( {{customerName}}

, red and black element as shown in pic) to be positioned as shown in pic number 3.

**I don't want this** 
[image]

**I want this**

[image]

Here is my code snippet
**Template.html**

```
<mat-form-field [style.cursor]="pointer"  [style.width.px]=320 >
  <input  id="inputCustomer" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto"  [formControl]="customerFilterControl" [(ngModel)]="customerName">
   <mat-icon style="font-family: Material Icons; height: 24px; width: 24px; fill: currentColor;font-weight:normal;line-height: 1; font-style: normal;font-size:24px;top:5px; " matSuffix>expand_more</mat-icon> 
   <p id="spandiv"}">{{customerName}}</p> // this is my concern
   <mat-autocomplete  ...>
    <mat-option>

    </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>


**css**
#spandiv {
  background-color: #6B6664;
  padding: 5px;
  color:white;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;

}


#inputCustomer:hover + #spandiv {
  position: relative;
  right: 125px;
  top:40px;
  display: inline;
}
```

On hovering input element( first element in pic) p element is displayed. P element width is dynamic it depends on customer selected as shown in pic2 and 3.

I want to position p element as shown in pic #3 how to do this?

Comment: Let me know If my question is not clear

Comment: I recommend putting both elements inside a parent div, and then adjusting the width of the two children elements to a certain % of the div. After that you will just have to play with alignment and padding.